# How to maintain the relation ship on more than two tables

Tags: database

Please help me on maintaining the relatoinships between more than two tables. I will explain the one scenario that i am facing now.
Table 1 has all the codes i am using in the application, example status codes means Active has the code as 10, InActive has the code as 20, in this way i am mainting all the codes, 
Table 2 is having the 5 columns,

```
column 1 is auto generated key
column 2 - has the id of table 1
column 3 - also has the id of table 1
column 4 - also has the id of table 1
column 5 - has description.
```

So,I need to perform multiple joins while retreiving the data from these two tables.My question is this, is it right way to maitain the tables?

Moreover i am using Spring with Hibernate to fetch the data from DB. Any ideas on how to do that using Hibernate?
Please suggest me on this.

Comment: The example you show has no relavnce to the question you ask.  Your example contains two tables, but you ask about relationships spanning more than two tables.

Comment: Sounds like you're duplicating data.

Comment: Check out 3rd normal form for decent database structure: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form Also remember not to use "id's" unless really necessary. It is usually a good idea to split data into as many tables as possible but be aware of data duplication if storage is an issue. Here's an excellent db course online: http://online.stanford.edu/db-win13

Comment: @span: I once saw a table `CREATE TABLE xxx(id GUID PRIMARY KEY, code CHAR(2) UNIQUE)` — I am still not sure why the DBA couldn't just made `code` field the primary key, I mean, the surrogate key is 8 times bigger than the actual data...

Comment: @span: Thanks Span for the answer. i will follow the link and ask questions if i have any.